# C# email client debugging blocked by computer

Tags: c#, email

I was working on the email client but in the middle of the work, debugger began to pop up blocked by the local device, but when it's not in visual studio it works without any problem, but only using another email because it began to block my test mail I originally used.

Comment: I can't tell if you're saying that it only works when you are not running it in Visual Studio or if you are saying that it only works when you are not running in Visual Studio _and_ you change the email address. Please clarify your language with reasonable grammar and punctuation. Also, you must provide details regarding how you are sending the email. Are you using SMTP client? And so on

Comment: When not in VS you are probably running As Admin.  VS will not run As Admin without creating a shortcut and then start VS from shortcut by right click as select Run As Admin.

Comment: I have set it to run like admin response to it is following error: "'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". No matter what email I use in the beginning it blocked only one my mail and now it won't let any it is a lot of updates of windows back When I tried it and it still keeps doing it tried even clean cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Visual Studio as admin. Right click Visual Studio icon, then click run as administrator.